# How i Can Update my Json data in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

I need help:

I saved my Discord bot ping in a JSON file and I want to show the ping from the JSON file in my web server using HTML. I am using Express.js.

This here is a picture of the data but it's not getting updated when it changes in the JSON file.

[image]

This in my express project:

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    const pingsBots = require('./Database/BotPing.json')

    const pingofbot = pingsBots.thepingofbot.botping

    let file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './html/', 'main.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' })
    file = file.replace("$$theping$$", pingofbot)

    
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './html/', 'main.html'))
    res.send(file)
    
})
```

And this in ready method in my bot:

```js
setInterval(function(){
        let Pusher = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Database/BotsPing.json', 'utf8'));
        Pusher["thepingofbot"] = {
            botping: `${client.ws.ping}`
        }
        async function SavePingData(path, JSONdata){
            fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(JSONdata, null, 2))
        }
        SavePingData('./Database/BotsPing.json', Pusher)
    }, 1000)
```

B.t.w.: Express project not with the bot project.

Comment: dont use `require` its cached, simply load the file with fs then JSON.stringify the json in like your doing, then when you want to change the value load the file, parse the json, alter the value then stringify and save again, you may also need atomic write on the file else depending on some factors file may get corrupted

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    const pingsBots = require('./Database/BotPing.json')
    const pingofbot = pingsBots.thepingofbot.botping
    let file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './html/', 'main.html'), { encoding: 'utf-8' })
    file = file.replace("$$theping$$", pingofbot) 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './html/', 'main.html'))
})
```